# ESXi 7.0.3 USB Device not show up after setting configuration

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

In ESXi console I can see my device with `lsusb` list
And in vm settings I add new USB Device and select my usb from dropdown list, and save settings.
But after that, I could neither see my device in windows server nor in vm configuration!
And when I try to add new device it doesn't show up in dropdown list anymore.
But still can see my device in `lsusb` list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the device in question is a USB storage device, specifically a flash drive.  A quick Google has this hit: "S102 Pro Advanced USB 3.2 Flash Drive | Buy Now".  AFAIK there is no workaround.  Gory details follow in the next paragraph.  Peruse at your own risk.

In vSphere ESXi 6.5 and earlier releases of ESXi the USB driver stack was a "vmklinux" driver stack with individual drivers for each device type, including USB host controllers.  Thus if your installation was on a SCSI disk or PXE booted over the network you didn't need the USB storage driver at all and you could unload it and then pass the device through to a VM.  Unloading the driver wasn't offically supported but could be done at the esxcli command line or if you wanted to be really daring you could delete it from your bootbank image.  Note that "deleting" was only theoretical as you would really be replacing the driver module with a file of size 0 in the last loaded tar image (the only one that is customer configurable) and could thus be undone, but I digress.

The new USB native driver stack that debuted in vSphere ESXi 6.7 is a monolithic driver which means that it is not possible to unload only the storage driver.  You could unload or clobber the entire USB stack but then you'd lose the keyboard and perhaps other things plus the ability to pass any USB device through to a VM.  The disadvantages of monolithic USB drivers are well known and are the reason that Linus himself got involved in the redesign of the long gone Linux monolithic USB driver from over a decade ago, but I again digress.  As to why VMware "improved" things by replacing a USB stack with half a dozen or more USB drivers with a monolithic stack with all the attendant disadvantages, you'd have to ask them.  Feel free to request that they break the driver up into constituent modules as they know how to do this.